# How to run lines of code everytime you open an application

Tags: python, scripting, discord, discord.js, discord.py

Wanted to know how I can run a couple lines of code everytime I launch an application.

For more detail, I want a message to be sent via discord everytime I launch a certain application. I have figured out how to send the message through discord using python, but have not been able to figure out how to execute this code whenever I open an application